# Android PipedOutputStream / PipedInputStream transfer byte by byte seems wrong

Tags: java, android, inputstream, outputstream

The Android implementation of PipedOutputStream

```
write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
```

is implemented in terms of write(byte oneByte).
More specific the PipedOutputStream

```
write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
```

is implemented by looping over the 
    byte[] buffer
and calling write(byte oneByte) for every byte. See [this](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/libcore.git;a=blob;f=luni/src/main/java/java/io/PipedOutputStream.java;h=6df3fa274cce8df9a7d7fa7bd2114798590ff40e;hb=HEAD) .

Doing it in this way results in a receive call on the PipedInputStream for every byte. This receive results in a notifyAll which wakes the reader and make it read. You get a lot of one byte reads in this way.

I can see that it is a correct implementation, but slow.
Is there maybe some Java convention which makes this wrong in some way? Because a write of an array on a PipedOutputStream is now interleaved with notifies to PipedInputStream.

write [a b c] results in write(a) notify write(b) notify write(c) notify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the code you linked seems to imply that it uses the default implementation of `OutputStream` to send each single `byte` as is. As far as I know, this **is** in fact correct, but probably pretty inefficient.

Comment: I already saw that it uses its own/android default implementation of OutputStream. Maybe there could be some convention for not writing an array copy in terms of a byte copy (because on every byte copy it does a notify of its readers). Maybe the android team wants to fix this then. In fact I lookup the oracle implementation and it uses the efficient implementation.

Comment: For a high performance pipe you can use java.nio.channels.Pipe